# Linear Programming problem with multi-way duty swap

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

With python and pulp I'm trying to solve a problem using linear programming.

I have this working code below which creates a multipoint swap solution based on allowed swaps. The problem is, I want to be able to limit the maximum number of participants in a multi-way swap. For example I would like to be able to limit the swaps to three-way swaps.

```
import pulp

# Sample data: List of requests
participants = ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie', 'David']
weights = {'Alice': 1, 'Bob': 3, 'Charlie': 2, 'David': 1}

# Sample data: Define which swaps are allowed based on your constraints. e.g. Alice to Bob
allowed_swaps = [('Alice', 'Bob'), ('Bob', 'Alice'), ('Bob', 'Charlie'), ('Charlie', 'David'),
                 ('Charlie', 'Alice'), ('Charlie', 'Bob'), ('David', 'Alice')]


swaps = pulp.LpVariable.dicts('Swap', allowed_swaps, cat='Binary')


model = pulp.LpProblem("DutySwap", pulp.LpMaximize)

model += pulp.lpSum((1000 + weights[p1] + weights[p2]) * swaps[(p1, p2)] for (p1, p2) in allowed_swaps)

for p in participants:
    model += pulp.lpSum(swaps[(p1, p2)] for (p1, p2) in allowed_swaps if p1 == p) <= 1
    model += pulp.lpSum(swaps[(p1, p2)] for (p1, p2) in allowed_swaps if p2 == p) <= 1
    model += (pulp.lpSum(swaps[(p1, p2)] for (p1, p2) in allowed_swaps if p1 == p)
              == pulp.lpSum(swaps[(p1, p2)] for (p1, p2) in allowed_swaps if p2 == p))
print(model)

status = model.solve()
for (p1, p2) in allowed_swaps:
    if pulp.value(swaps[(p1, p2)]) == 1:
        print(f"{p1}'s duty goes to {p2}")

# This will output
# Alice's duty goes to Bob
# Bob's duty goes to Charlie
# Charlie's duty goes to David
# David's duty goes to Alice
```

With the allowed swaps entered I would like to be able to limit the multi-way swap to (for example) a three-way swap which in this case would result in.

```
# Alice's duty goes to Bob
# Bob's duty goes to Charlie
# Charlie's duty goes to Alice
```

I can't think of a way to enter constraints which make this possible. Do you have an idea for a solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just limit the total swap?

```py
import pulp


weights = {'Alice': 1, 'Bob': 3, 'Charlie': 2, 'David': 1}
participants = weights.keys()

# Sample data: Define which swaps are allowed based on your constraints. e.g. Alice to Bob
allowed_swaps = [
    ('Alice', 'Bob'),
    ('Bob', 'Alice'),
    ('Bob', 'Charlie'),
    ('Charlie', 'David'),
    ('Charlie', 'Alice'),
    ('Charlie', 'Bob'),
    ('David', 'Alice'),
]

swaps = pulp.LpVariable.dicts(name='Swap', indices=allowed_swaps, cat='Binary')

model = pulp.LpProblem('DutySwap', pulp.LpMaximize)
model.objective = pulp.lpDot(
    swaps.values(),
    (
        (1000 + weights[p1] + weights[p2])
        for (p1, p2) in allowed_swaps
    ),
)

for p in participants:
    source_sum = pulp.lpSum(
        swaps[(p1, p2)] for (p1, p2) in allowed_swaps if p1 == p)
    dest_sum = pulp.lpSum(
        swaps[(p1, p2)] for (p1, p2) in allowed_swaps if p2 == p)
    model.addConstraint(source_sum <= 1)
    model.addConstraint(dest_sum <= 1)
    model.addConstraint(source_sum == dest_sum)

model.addConstraint(pulp.lpSum(swaps.values()) <= 3)

print(model)
model.solve()
assert model.status == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

for p1, p2 in allowed_swaps:
    if pulp.value(swaps[(p1, p2)]) > 0.5:
        print(f"{p1:>7s}'s duty goes to {p2}")
```

```
  Alice's duty goes to Bob
    Bob's duty goes to Charlie
Charlie's duty goes to Alice
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That would work in this case but I'm trying to use this with 50+ allowed swaps :)

Comment: If it doesn't work for 4, please add an example to your question